# Is it possible to assign a value to a divergent series in a residue system

Tags: number-theory

For example,
$$\sum^\infty_0{n!} \ \mod{21}$$
For n>=7, every term will have factors 7 and 3, so will be a multiple of 21, so
$$\sum^\infty_0{n!} \equiv \sum^6_0{n!} \ \mod{21}$$
In which case 
$$\sum^\infty_0{n!}\equiv 12\mod{21}$$
Although I don't see an application this, my question is whether it is mathematically valid to make this claim as it seems strange to me, but I cannot think of an argument against it.

Comment: Congratulations. You are about to (re)invented the $p$-adic numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number. It's a very useful tool and has enormous applications.

Comment: The assignment makes sense since the residue becomes "stationary" , but strictly speaking we cannot assign a residue to a diverging sum, since it has no finite value.